# Community Advanced Audience configuration

Tags: community, custom-object, customer-community, community-builder

Good afternoon.
I am trying to set up an audience by assigning a record type. However, the object I want does not appear in the list:

[image]

[image]

Is this a setup that should be done in Salesforce? Remembering that i'm using Admin user.

EDIT: Object permissions
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is the object that you are trying to use here exists in your Org? What is the name of the Object that you are trying to refer here? Providing these details will additionally help anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @JayantDas I changed my post. Yes, this object exists in my Org.
In print I put it as "Gos" but it's actually "Goal". The problem happens in the QA environment. In development it works.

Comment: So don’t you see `Goal` at all? If you see it in one environment and not other then you should ensure that the visibility os set appropriately on the object.

Comment: @JayantDas That is the problem. I compared the permissions to this object under Development and QA and it is identical.

Comment: Do you see the object name in the list when you don't type anything in there? You will always get the list of all objects available in the Org if you just place the cursor in the input box in that screen.

Comment: @JayantDas I don't see the object typing its name or not

Comment: I am quite sure then this has to do something with the visibility of the object. You may like to verify all possible aspects around it.

Comment: @JayantDas I added in my question a print with the permissions of the object. You can see that I have access to record types and full object modification.

Comment: Solved! It's the language in Salesforce

Comment: You may like to add the details as an answer so that others in same situation benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I changed the Salesforce language

Comment: Can you share any more explanation as to how changing the language affected/caused/cured this problem?